# Add existing asp.net to IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net

I have zero experience with IIS and have to be able to load an existing asp.net application onto it (or any web server that can handle asp.net just fine).

What's the best way of taking a document of the web root and getting it to work with IIS? Is there a specific import process? Do I have to worry about running something that grabs third party dependencies/modules?

Comment: it depend of the project, if it is a basic one, just copy past your web content in the IIS root folder, and check what append, try to chec all pages. After there s lot of configurations you can make (or was already made), if you are lucky you should find a .xml in root folder with website config. Any one did a doc for this project ? can you contact the old dev for infos ?

Comment: I think you need to configure IIS (and install MSSQL if needed) first and then copy the files and try to deploy. Check this link and do the necessary for IIS configuration and see if it works: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-deploying-to-iis-as-a-test-environment-5-of-12

Comment: This can also be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22902320/migrate-a-asp-net-application-from-one-server-to-another-server

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have the .NET framework required installed on your web server. This can be achieved through the Server manager on windows server. When you create your website in IIS you need to select the specific .NET framework application pool (Depending on what version of .NET your ASP.NET application is written in). Set your bindings and settings and deploy! Simply then, Publish (Compile) your ASP.NET application and copy those published files to the new directory you created for your site. After clicking browse you should see your site.

Also, Here is a link explaining my tutorial much more in-depth:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis